# Loop through individual UITableViewCells in UITableView in order to edit text in cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am currently trying to loop through the cells of a UITableView in order to strikeout particular UILabels contained in the related viewController.

How would I go about doing this?

**Context:** The array specialBool contains 6 bools. The index position corresponds to a product that is either on special or not. If the bool is true then I want the label (previousPrice) in that particular product cell to be struck out... if it is false then the label should remain normal.

This is my code so far. It is incomplete:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! exploreTableView

cell.photo.image = globalVariable.images[indexPath.row]
cell.name.text = globalVariable.names[indexPath.row]
cell.price.text = globalVariable.prices[indexPath.row]
cell.unitPrice.text = globalVariable.unitPrice[indexPath.row]
cell.pPrice.text = globalVariable.previousPrice[indexPath.row]

    var i = 0
    while i < globalVariable.previousPrice.count {
        if (globalVariable.specialBool[i] == true) {

            // Strike through previous price
            let attributeString: NSMutableAttributedString =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: globalVariable.previousPrice[i])
            attributeString.addAttribute(NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributeString.length))
            cell.pPrice.attributedText = attributeString;

        } else {
            cell.pPrice.text = globalVariable.previousPrice[i]

        }
        i += 1
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of the code to your question as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first understand what are you doing and what you want to do. Get good understanding of `UITableView`

You do not need the while loop and also `cellForRowAtIndexPath` calls for each visible cells(These cells reused for other index paths).

```
//Remove while loop and var i = 0

//This will call for each visible cell so replace `i` with indexPath.row
if globalVariable.specialBool[indexPath.row] == true {
 // do your work here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looping through each cells? Inside your tableview delegate method: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, implement your code to manage the label.

```
BOOL boolVal = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (boolVal) {
    //strike out previous price label.
}else {
    //keep the label normal.
}
```

When ever you want to loop through the cells, just call `[tableView reloadData]` to reload all the cells in UITableView.